# Stop audio recording and continue audio playback

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, avaudiosession

My application plays music and records from mic at the same time. Recording can be started after playback is started or before playback is started

And now I want to *stop recording but keep playback running* at the same time.

How can I do this?

I can stop recording *and* playback by using

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
```

But the issue is: I want to stop recording only.

I tried to change category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` using the following code

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error]
```

but that doesn't stop recording.

Comment: Did you have an issue that you can't play and record simultaneously? When my app starts playing audio, it uncontrollably stops recording...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by explicitly stopping all recording activity without touching AVAudioSession at all.

The following warning

> AVAudioSession.mm:623: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]:
>   Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be
>   stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

helped me to identify the issue.

Initially I forgot to call the `AudioOutputUnitStop` method of AudioUnit framework. Because of this recording process was still running and audio session were indicating that.

Comment: how did you fix it , please tell me .. Thx

Comment: @Bobrovsky how you fix this issue?